# MySQL query only returns value if rows exist

Tags: mysql, sum, left-join

I have the following query which works perfectly, but only if each select finds a row.

I've attempted to add IFNULL to return 0 if no rows were found but I'm still not getting the correct return.

```
SELECT IFNULL(paid_value,0)-IFNULL(ordered_value,0)+IFNULL(credit_value,0) AS account_balance
            FROM
            (
              SELECT customer_id, SUM(order_total) AS ordered_value
              FROM orders
              WHERE customer_id = '1'
              GROUP BY customer_id
            ) AS orders
            LEFT JOIN
            (
              SELECT customer_id, SUM(amount) AS paid_value
              FROM transactions
              WHERE customer_id = '1'
              GROUP BY customer_id
            ) as payments
            ON orders.customer_id = payments.customer_id
            LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT customer_id, SUM(amount) AS credit_value
                FROM credits
                WHERE customer_id = '1'
                GROUP BY customer_id
            ) as credits
            ON orders.customer_id = credits.customer_id
```

This query currently returns empty, it's not returning NULL or 0.

When I run

```
              SELECT customer_id, SUM(order_total) AS ordered_value
              FROM orders
              WHERE customer_id = '1'
              GROUP BY customer_id
```

It also returns empty, not NULL or 0, unless there's a row. In order for the full query to work, each of the 3 separate queries need to have a row in them.

Any ideas?

Comment: I hope you have Table for Customer

Comment: Yes, I do, but that's not the issue.

Comment: I know that is not issue. Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It if because none of the columns have a result set, so an empty result set is returned, if you want to always display a row in any case you can try with some tricks like this one for example :

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(payments.paid_value),0)-IFNULL(SUM(orders .ordered_value),0)+IFNULL(SUM(credits.credit_value),0) AS account_balance
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS idx, 0 AS paid_value, 0 AS ordered_value, 0 AS credit_value) a
LEFT JOIN
            (
              SELECT 1 AS idx, customer_id, SUM(order_total) AS ordered_value
              FROM orders
              WHERE customer_id = '1'
              GROUP BY customer_id
            ) AS orders
            ON a.idx = orders.idx 
            LEFT JOIN
            (
              SELECT customer_id, SUM(amount) AS paid_value
              FROM transactions
              WHERE customer_id = '1'
              GROUP BY customer_id
            ) as payments
            ON orders.customer_id = payments.customer_id
            LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT customer_id, SUM(amount) AS credit_value
                FROM credits
                WHERE customer_id = '1'
                GROUP BY customer_id
            ) as credits
            ON orders.customer_id = credits.customer_id
            GROUP BY a.idx
```

The example is a proof of concept that can be adapted even to other situations where you need to always returns a row with default values even with no elements in underlying tables .

Comment: I receive the error: Column 'paid_value' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: @Karl , In top most select use a.paid_value ... for all columns.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out, thanks @aleroot. However, there's still an issue. I know for a fact the customer ID I'm using has no orders, no transactions, but definitely has a credit for 66. But it returns 0.00 as the account balance instead of 66.00. Any ideas?

Comment: Done a bit of playing around and I've found out that if the SELECT for the credits comes first, I get the right account balance (66.00), however, if it's last I get 0.00. Why should the ordering of the selects matter?

Comment: Figured out that changing `ON orders.customer_id = payments.customer_id` to `ON a.idx = payments.customer_id` and `ON orders.customer_id = credits.customer_id` to `ON a.idx = credits.customer_id` fixed the issue. Unsure why this fixed it though?

Answer (score 0):

If you want row event if there is no data available, then I suppose you should either have `UNION`. Or In this scenario you can include you Customer Table & put each Table on Right Side, make a `LEFT JOIN`.

I think following select will give you an IDEA.

```
SELECT O.customer_id, SUM(O.order_total) AS ordered_value
              FROM Customers C
              left join orders O on C.ID =o.customer_id
              WHERE O.customer_id = '1'
              GROUP BY O.customer_id
```